# How to replace the numbering from 1 to .... for breadcrumb schema data?

Tags: php, schema, metadata, breadcrumbs

I want to put automatic numbering in `content=""` tag how to fill this numbering, please answer with the code run script?

Code

```html
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses">
    <span itemprop="name">Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="**numbering**" />
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses/real">
    <span itemprop="name">Real Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="**numbering**" />
  </li>
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses/real">
    <span itemprop="name">Real Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="**numbering**" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For HTMLcods you can add run section which helps reviewers run your codes here. Accordingly, they are interested more to response your question. In addition, please add some other tags for your question such as HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<ol>...</ol>` instead of `<ul>...</ul>` which will automatically provide you numbered list.

For more info: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_intro